# Php mysql group by sum issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

Got this code
HTML

```
<div class="ultventas_group" ng-repeat="mesa in mesas">
  <div class="ultventas_group_item">MESA {{mesa.table_number}}</div>
  <div class="ultventas_group_price">$ {{mesa.price}}</div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include('base.php');
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT table_number, SUM(price) as totalprice FROM orders GROUP BY table_number LIMIT 30");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data = $row;
    }
}else {
    echo "0 results";
};
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Angularjs

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../php/getTableList.php'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = 'No Response';
  });
```

DB

Has two columns price and table_number. On which i got three values.

```
1. table_number=1 price = 30
1. table_number=1 price = 30
1. table_number=5 price = 60
```

With this code i'm supposed to get as result

```
1. table_number=1 price = 60
1. table_number=5 price = 60
```

But i'm getting just:

```
1. table_number=1 price = 30
1. table_number=5 price = 60
```

The first row is bringing as price, the price of the only first row and it's ignoring all the other ones, i tried with table_number 5 and it's the same issue.

Comment: Can you post your table structure with data?

Comment: Please edit your question and give a _reproducible_ sample problem, with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs here:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data = $row; // overwrite $data with new value.
  }
}else {
  echo "0 results";
};
```

Instead do this:

```
$data[] = $row;
```

Since you're not doing anything special with each row data, you might want to use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead.

```
if(count($data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) > 0){
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```